# JavaScript move object

Tags: javascript, html

i have a script for move DOM object, but it doesn't work, i think troubles in my keydown countruction where im trying to add/subtract and nothing happens. Can somebody explain why?

```
    mouse.setAttribute('tabindex', '0')
    alert(typeof(+mouse.style.left));
    mouse.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        mouse.style.position = 'fixed';

        mouse.style.left = mouse.getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px';
        mouse.style.top = mouse.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px';
    })

    mouse.addEventListener ('focus', (event) =>  {
      mouse.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            if (event.keyCode == 37){
                console.log('left');
                let left = +mouse.style.left
                mouse.style.left = left - 20 + 'px';
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 38){
                console.log('up');
                let up = +mouse.style.top;
                mouse.style.top = up - 20 + 'px';
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 39){
                console.log('right');
                let right = +mouse.style.left
                mouse.style.left = right +  20 + 'px';
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 40){
                console.log('down');
                let down = +mouse.style.top
                mouse.style.top = down + 20 + 'px';
            }
        })  
    })
    
    
  </script>
```

Comment: The element's `style.top` (or `left`) is not a Number, its a String. So you can't do math on it with the `+=` or `-=` operator. You'll need to parse that value as a number first, then perform your math, then set the value back.

Comment: Hey @fetixzz, can you add some more info about what `mouse` is exactly?

Pay attention that the top/right/bottom/left attributes are strings so you would have to parse the number. (parseInt/parseFloat/Number constructor).

One last thing I noticed, it looks like that only when you focus on the "mouse" you attach an event listener. Feels like every time you'll focus, a new eventListener will be attached?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And please turn this into a [mcve] using the runnable snippet functionality: edit your post, and then create an html/css/jss example that shows off the problem when folks run it on this page. Also, on a JS note, don't compare with `==`, use `===` unless the only way to do what you need to do _relies_ on type coercion (which is almost never).

Comment: Hey, i parsed to int but nothing changed, object doesn't move. I edited my code in this topic. It works as i take focus on object and after i able to move it by keydown. Every event its working, i can see it in console, but coords of object don't change @SimonIfergan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` does not parse a string such as `'20px'` as `20`. As mentioned in the comments, you need to parse your styles as a number. This means using a function such as `parseInt` as demonstrated below.

Also, registering an event handler inside an event handler may not result in what you wish. In particular: If you focus the `div` twice, the event handler will run twice.

```js
var mouse = document.getElementById('mouse');
mouse.setAttribute('tabindex', '0')
mouse.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    mouse.style.position = 'fixed';

    mouse.style.left = mouse.getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px';
    mouse.style.top = mouse.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px';
})

mouse.addEventListener ('focus', (event) =>  {
  mouse.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode == 37){
            console.log('left');
            let left = parseInt(mouse.style.left)
            mouse.style.left = left - 20 + 'px';
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 38){
            console.log('up');
            let up = parseInt(mouse.style.top);
            mouse.style.top = up - 20 + 'px';
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39){
            console.log('right');
            let right = parseInt(mouse.style.left)
            mouse.style.left = right +  20 + 'px';
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40){
            console.log('down');
            let down = parseInt(mouse.style.top)
            mouse.style.top = down + 20 + 'px';
        }
    })  
})
```

```html
<div id="mouse" style="background-color: yellow">Hi</div>
```